# Point in Polygon method in R for merge regions of a shapefile with over 15'000 observations of a dataset

Tags: r

I am struggling since  days  with a problem.

| region | geometry |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | MULTIPOLYGON(6830854,.... |
| 2 | MULTIPOLYGON(6830854,.... |

| gisid | geox | geoy | drug dependency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 800000 | 150000 | 65 |
| 2 | 600000 | 300000 | 80 |

The new  dataset should look llike this

| Region | mean (drug depency) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 55 |
| 2 | 54 |

for example region 1 contains gisid 4,5,8,9,50, 65, 83 and they lie in the region 1 and then calculate the mean value of drug depency. I couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a somewhat contrived example. The key function is `st_intersection()`. There may be faster solutions using other methods in `sf`.

```
library(sf)
library(tmap)
library(tidyverse)
data("World")
world.centroids <- st_centroid(World)[,1]
world.centroids.expanded <- world.centroids[rep(row.names(world.centroids), 3),]
world.centroids.expanded$ref <- runif(nrow(world.centroids.expanded), 0 ,1 )
intersections <- st_intersection(World[,1], world.centroids.expanded)
intersections <- st_drop_geometry(intersections)
intersections |> group_by(iso_a3) |> summarise(avg = mean(ref))

# A tibble: 164 × 2
   iso_a3   avg
   <fct>  <dbl>
 1 AFG    0.382
 2 AGO    0.457
 3 ALB    0.510
 4 ARE    0.359
 5 ARG    0.627
 6 ARM    0.361
 7 ATA    0.130
 8 ATF    0.241
 9 AUS    0.636
10 AUT    0.304
```